# PHP Composer on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After completing the EB "example-application", I downloaded what I believe is the original php application zip from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.DeployApp.html and made a couple of couple of changes in the text only (like modifying one `<p>` to contain `hello world`)...

When I tried uploading and deploying the "modified" app EB showed me "Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'composer.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install Composer dependencies."
So I created a composer.json and ran `composer update` which created a vendor folder. But even after this I still got the same errors. I looked at similar questions on Stackoverflow and tried following their solutions but none of them helped. Here's what my directory looks like

```
.ebextensions
      logging.config
vendor
      composer
             autoload_classmap.php
             autoload_namespaces.php
             autoload_psr4.php
             autoload_real.php
             autoload_static.php
             ClassLoader.php
             installed.json
             LICENSE
      monolog
             monolog
                    ...
      autoload.php
composer.json
composer.lock
cron.yaml
index.php
logo_aws_reduced.gif
scheduled.php
styles.css
```

If it helps, you can [download the zip from docs.amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/php-v1.zip)

Comment: Have zip file is for old Amazon LInux 1 environment. Have you tried using this, or are you using current version of EB env which is Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: I'm using the current version of Elastic Beanstalk, running on Amazon Linux 2

Comment: So try on the old version with Amazon Linux 1. The php zip from amazon will not work properly  on AL2 anyway.

Comment: So why do they say to use a zip?? I did get the PHP working btw, just having issues with Composer

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76359381/12326605

Answer (score 2):

It's a false error message. From the docs:
When Elastic Beanstalk finds a vendor folder on the instance, it ignores the composer.json file (even if it exists). Your application then uses dependencies from the vendor folder.