# Why Can't I Run Composer Install on Deploy in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Apparently I'm missing something when trying to deploy my application in EB. I'm getting this error:

> Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'composer.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install Composer dependencies.

I'm following the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). Here's a view of the file structure:

```
.
|____Buildfile
|____composer.json
|____composer.lock
|____index.php
|____api
| |____v1
| | |____index.php
```

My Buildfile:

```
01_composer_install: composer install
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
I tried adding the .platform hooks with no success. Same error.
New tree structure:

```
.
|____.platform
| |____hooks
| | |____predeploy
| | | |____01_composer_install.sh
|____composer.json
|____composer.lock
|____index.php
|____api
| |____v1
| | |____index.php
```

`01_composer_install.sh` contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
composer install
```

Comment: Your question is missing the command that does summon the error message. What is the command? How and where is it entered? Additionally from the question it is not clear how and where you generate the tree structure (as displayed). Is this the listing of the zip file? Is that done manually as you look into your file-manager and from disk (not an archive file like zip) and you type it into the question manually? Please add those clarifications. Also if not yet, please add the listing of files as in the source boundle that is going to be uploaded to the remote service.

Comment: Could you run a `ls` from the script to see whether it it executed in the folder that should contain the composer.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your zip file (assuming you uploaded as zip) has a directory on top. That is, if you look at the zip structure it will be

```
MyProject
|
--- composer.json
```

Make sure that if you zip from File Explorer, you select files in the folder and not the folder itself. I see it happening all the time

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to run `composer install` manually. When a `composer.json` file is present, Elastic Beanstalk runs `composer.phar install` to install dependencies for you. And, when Elastic Beanstalk finds a vendor folder on the instance, it ignores the `composer.json` file (even if it exists). Your application then uses dependencies from the vendor folder.

Source: [Installing your application's dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-configuration-composer.html)

Further, in case you want to sets custom options to use when installing dependencies using Composer through `composer.phar` install, you can defines `composer_options` in the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini` namespace in the configuration file of `.ebextensions`. For example:-
**.ebextensions/php-settings.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    document_root: /public
    memory_limit: 128M
    zlib.output_compression: "Off"
    allow_url_fopen: "On"
    display_errors: "Off"
    max_execution_time: 60
    composer_options: vendor/package
```

sources:

- [Using the Elastic Beanstalk PHP platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html)
- [PHP platform options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-php)

Regarding the error, as you are trying to execute `composer install`  with buildfile and hooks, it might not be running at the root of your application source code so it couldn't find the composer.json file, so you might need to specify the absolute path of your composer.json with composer install, although I'm not very much sure on this part.

I hope this helps.

Comment: in regard to _"specify the absolute path of your composer.json"_ - this is possible per `COMPOSER` parameter, but in this case perhaps more direct/better with `-d`, `--working-dir=WORKING-DIR`  (_"If specified, use the given directory as working directory."_ from `composer --help`).