# Php - Instance deployment failed to install Composer dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have just started learning Laravel and I have configured a code pipeline to deploy my sample Laravel application on an EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk.

Application deployment was working fine without any issues.

However, after removing an existing package and adding another one in the *composer.json* file, the deployment is failing with the below error.

*Instance deployment failed to install Composer dependencies specified in 'composer.json' in your source bundle. aws pipeline*

I found several answers related to this issue but none of them worked for me. I defined the *.ebextension* folder with *01-composer-install.config* file in it. The file has the following contents:

```
commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

However, this does not resolve the issue.

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-configuration-composer.html), "When Elastic Beanstalk finds a vendor folder on the instance, it ignores the composer.json file (even if it exists). Your application then uses dependencies from the vendor folder".

My assumption is that the *vendor* folder already exists on the EC2 instance, that's why it doesn't install the new dependencies.

To resolve this issue temporarily, I have removed the *vendor* folder from the *.gitignore* and after running the `composer install`, I pushed the complete *vendor* folder into the repo and the deployment was successful this time.

My question is, is this the only way to deploy changes after a dependency is changed in the *composer.json* file? If not then how can we resolve the error generated during the deployment?

Comment: Did you check the composer.lock file, probably in your composer lock old package still included.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76359381/12326605

Answer (score 1):

It's now not necessary to upload the whole `vendor` folder on your Git repository when deploying a Laravel utility on Elastic Beanstalk. Committing the `vendor` folder is usually now not recommended because it may bloat your repository and purpose model conflicts.

Instead Update Composer on Your Local Machine using

```bash
  composer self-replace
```

Then Update `composer.json` then run

```bash
composer install
```

This will update your vendor directory with the latest dependencies based on the changes you made to `composer.json`.

then commit `composer.json` and `composer.lock`:

```bash
git add composer.json composer.lock
git commit -m "Update composer.json and composer.lock"
git push
```

Your Elastic Beanstalk environment should be configured to run Composer during deployment. You've already created the .ebextensions folder, but you need to ensure that your environment is set up correctly to run Composer during the deployment process.

Create a file named `.ebextensions/01-composer-install.config` with the following content:

```yaml
container_commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: "export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update"
  02_install_dependencies:
    command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader"
```

Elastic Beanstalk will use the updated `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files to install the necessary dependencies during deployment.

Comment: self-replace is not correct, do you mean self-update?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things to resolve this issue including @arpan.r's answer but none worked.

I created a source bundle including vendor folder and the deployed application successfully, finally.

And this is from eb-engine.log:

```
CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: You included a 'vendor' folder in your source bundle. The deployment ignored 'composer.json' and didn't install Composer dependencies.","timestamp":1708681897886,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1708681912291,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}
```